# Glassfish Full Feature List

Tags: glassfish-3

I'm looking for some sort of feature list for GlassFish v3. Does anyone know where to find such a list?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any full feature list. I think the features have to be derived from the technologies / specification that Glassfish implements and supports.

A good starting point could be the [Glassfish release notes](http://glassfish.java.net/docs/3.1/release-notes.pdf), although only features that are new to that release are listed.